# Are these two functional analysis books similar in content covered and the treatment of that content?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have been in touch with the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig.

Recently, I have been able to find another book: *Elements of Functional Analysis* by A.L. Brown and A. Page.

I wonder how similar (or different) the latter book is to the former.

Is it a good idea to read both books at the same time? Or else, which book should be read first?

Which book is more detailed? More advanced?

Does either book supplement or complement the other?

Is the book by Brown and Page more or less rigorous than that by Kreyszig? I have found Kreyszig's book to be lacking in rigor and detail at certain points.

Any courses taught using Kreyszig? Any courses taught using Brown and Page? I would appreciate links to the course webpages.

Comment: I took a course in functional analysis that used Kreyszig's text few years back and I seem to remember that when I had some difficulty in following proofs in Kreyszig, I usually looked up two books, one of which was Brown and Page.

Comment: @PJK where and when was that course taught? Is there any course webpage?

Comment: @PJK and which other book did you use along with Page & Brown in order to remove your difficulties with Kreyszig's proofs?

Comment: It was Bachman and Narici's text.